# In this informal definition of continuity (at $x=p$), what does "regardless of the manner in which $x$ approaches $p$" mean?

Tags: continuity

In my book it gave the informal definition of continuity as

> If we let $x$ move toward $p$, we want the corresponding function values $f(x)$ to become arbitrarily close to $f(p)$, regardless of the manner in which $x$ approaches $p$.

I don't understand what they mean when they say "regardless of the manner in which $x$ approaches $p$". I need some assistance.

Comment: On $\mathbb R$ it means you can approache either from the left or from the right; in $\mathbb R^2$ you can approache as you want inside a disk of center $p$ and so on according your respective neighborhood.

Comment: When you quote a book, it's good to also give it's title & author. Is this a calc book? Is it discussing multi-variable calculus? Limits in multi-variable calculus need to exist independent of the path taken as the point is approached, which is true in general - but in single variable calc there are only two paths, where as in multi-variable calc there are infinitely many.

Comment: @Joe- Sorry, I didn't consider it, the title is "Calculus" , Author- Tom Apostol. I don't know what multi-variable calculus is but judging by the way you say single variable calculus, I am studying single variable calculus

Comment: single variable calculus predominantly studies functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Multi-variable calculus studies functions from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for $n>1$, e.g. $f(x,y)= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what they mean is that regardless of what sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=p$ that you choose, you have that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)= f(p)$. It just means that if $x$ is close to $p$, then $f(x)$ is close to $f(p)$.